# Javascript: cut string and return in different inputs

Tags: javascript, string

I'm trying to cut a string in different part, and return each part into a different input. Here's an example:

Consider the following string: `Hello|World|!`

As you can see, there is a separator, which is `|`. I'd like to separate each part of the string cut by this `|` and return them into a different input.

I can't use `str.substr()` *(at least the usual use of it, maybe you have a trick)* because the number of characters between the `|` is not fixed, sometimes it will be 2 characters, sometimes 16, and from what I know `str.substr()` requires to set the number of characters before the cut.

Basically I'm looking for a solution as Excel provides in the Convert feature, where you define a separator and Excel will separate each part of the value into different cells each times he finds the separator set.

This is the first part of the Javascript, taking the value of the textarea where the string is pasted:

```
function cutTheString()
{
  var str = document.getElementById('textarea').value;
}
```

And this would be the HTML:

```
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Cut string" onClick="cutTheString()" />
<input type="text" id="string1"></input>
<input type="text" id="string2"></input>
<input type="text" id="string3"></input>
```

For now I have `document.getElementById('string1').value = str();` which returns the full string into the first input. I also have the possibility to transform the separator `|` into `,` by using `var res = str.split("|");` but that doesn't really help my case.

Comment: [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) returns an **array**. What else do you need?

Comment: I need to return each part of the strings into different input, not in one single input.

Comment: Ever heard of loops?

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but I thought I was the one asking a question :') Do you have any example code, or link that would show me how to do what I'm trying to? Thanks :)

Comment: If you followed a link I provided in my first reply you would've already had your answer. Nevertheless I posted it for you.

Comment: I followed it, and the first example given is close to what I'm searching for. But I don't see anywhere any example or explanation on how to return each part of the string into different input. Instead, it just returns the entire string, cut with a different separator than before passing in the function, into one single HTML element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing that you have enough `<input>` elements:

```
function cutTheString()
{
  var str = document.getElementById('textarea').value;
  var arrayOfStrings = str.split('|');
  for(var i = 0; i < arrayOfStrings.length; i++) {
     document.getElementById("string" + (i+1)).value = arrayOfStrings[i];
  }
}
```

See [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rbhjsdz8/2/).

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    var myString = 'hello|world|!';
    var myArray = myString.split('|')
    document.getElementById('string1').value = myArray[0];
    document.getElementById('string2').value = myArray[1];
    document.getElementById('string3').value = myArray[2];

</script>

<div>
    <input type='text' id='string1'></input>
    <input type='text' id='string2'></input>
    <input type='text' id='string3'></input>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `getElementById` within a loop, just as:

```
foreach{ getElementById(i++)} var result = result.contact();
```

Other way  you can use jquery, it has tag selectors.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Although, either I quite don't really understand it, or it will not do what I'm searching for. I have a big string inside a textarea with a single id, and I want to cut that string each time there is a specific separator, then return all the parts of the cut strings into different inputs. So I don't see how getting an id several times would help, because there's only one id as source of the string.