# Converting if...else statement into for-loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have one generous piece of code with several if...else statements and I would need to convert this into a loop. The problem is, each time it makes a loop, there must be some different id to the function so it works properly.

Let's take a look at the code:

```
// Count how many inputs there are in element with id "tempResult"
var inputCount = document.getElementById('tempResult').getElementsByTagName('input').length;


if (inputCount == 1)  // if there is 1 input, generate 1 line
{
  var str = document.getElementById('tempString1').value;
  var arrayOfStrings1 = str.split('*');
  for(var i = 0; i < arrayOfStrings1.length; i++)
  {
    var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
    var mi1 = document.createElement('input');
    mi1.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    mi1.setAttribute('size', '5');
    mi1.setAttribute('id', 'string1' + (i+1));
    mi1.setAttribute('value', arrayOfStrings1[i]);
    div1.appendChild(mi1);
  }
}
else if (inputCount == 2) // if there are 2 inputs, generate 2 lines
{
  var str = document.getElementById('tempString1').value;
  var arrayOfStrings1 = str.split('*');
  for(var i = 0; i < arrayOfStrings1.length; i++)
  {
    var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
    var mi1 = document.createElement('input');
    mi1.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    mi1.setAttribute('size', '5');
    mi1.setAttribute('id', 'string1' + (i+1));
    mi1.setAttribute('value', arrayOfStrings1[i]);
    div1.appendChild(mi1);
  }


  var str = document.getElementById('tempString2').value;
  var arrayOfStrings2 = str.split('*');
  for(var i = 0; i < arrayOfStrings2.length; i++)
  {
    var div2 = document.getElementById('div2');
    var mi2 = document.createElement('input');
    mi2.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    mi2.setAttribute('size', '5');
    mi2.setAttribute('id', 'string2' + (i+1));
    mi2.setAttribute('value', arrayOfStrings2[i]);
    div2.appendChild(mi2);
  }
}
else if (inputCount == 3) // if there are 3 inputs, generate 3 lines
{
  var str = document.getElementById('tempString1').value;
  var arrayOfStrings1 = str.split('*');
  for(var i = 0; i < arrayOfStrings1.length; i++)
  {
    var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
    var mi1 = document.createElement('input');
    mi1.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    mi1.setAttribute('size', '5');
    mi1.setAttribute('id', 'string1' + (i+1));
    mi1.setAttribute('value', arrayOfStrings1[i]);
    div1.appendChild(mi1);
  }


  var str = document.getElementById('tempString2').value;
  var arrayOfStrings2 = str.split('*');
  for(var i = 0; i < arrayOfStrings2.length; i++)
  {
    var div2 = document.getElementById('div2');
    var mi2 = document.createElement('input');
    mi2.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    mi2.setAttribute('size', '5');
    mi2.setAttribute('id', 'string2' + (i+1));
    mi2.setAttribute('value', arrayOfStrings2[i]);
    div2.appendChild(mi2);
  }


  var str = document.getElementById('tempString3').value;
  var arrayOfStrings3 = str.split('*');
  for(var i = 0; i < arrayOfStrings3.length; i++)
  {
    var div3 = document.getElementById('div3');
    var mi3 = document.createElement('input');
    mi3.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    mi3.setAttribute('size', '5');
    mi3.setAttribute('id', 'string3' + (i+1));
    mi3.setAttribute('value', arrayOfStrings3[i]);
    div3.appendChild(mi3);
  }
}
else if (inputCount == 4) // if there are 4 inputs, generate 4 lines
{
  var str = document.getElementById('tempString1').value;
  var arrayOfStrings1 = str.split('*');
  for(var i = 0; i < arrayOfStrings1.length; i++)
  {
    var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
    var mi1 = document.createElement('input');
    mi1.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    mi1.setAttribute('size', '5');
    mi1.setAttribute('id', 'string1' + (i+1));
    mi1.setAttribute('value', arrayOfStrings1[i]);
    div1.appendChild(mi1);
  }


  var str = document.getElementById('tempString2').value;
  var arrayOfStrings2 = str.split('*');
  for(var i = 0; i < arrayOfStrings2.length; i++)
  {
    var div2 = document.getElementById('div2');
    var mi2 = document.createElement('input');
    mi2.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    mi2.setAttribute('size', '5');
    mi2.setAttribute('id', 'string2' + (i+1));
    mi2.setAttribute('value', arrayOfStrings2[i]);
    div2.appendChild(mi2);
  }


  var str = document.getElementById('tempString3').value;
  var arrayOfStrings3 = str.split('*');
  for(var i = 0; i < arrayOfStrings3.length; i++)
  {
    var div3 = document.getElementById('div3');
    var mi3 = document.createElement('input');
    mi3.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    mi3.setAttribute('size', '5');
    mi3.setAttribute('id', 'string3' + (i+1));
    mi3.setAttribute('value', arrayOfStrings3[i]);
    div3.appendChild(mi3);
  }


  var str = document.getElementById('tempString4').value;
  var arrayOfStrings4 = str.split('*');
  for(var i = 0; i < arrayOfStrings4.length; i++)
  {
    var div4 = document.getElementById('div4');
    var mi4 = document.createElement('input');
    mi4.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    mi4.setAttribute('size', '5');
    mi4.setAttribute('id', 'string4' + (i+1));
    mi4.setAttribute('value', arrayOfStrings4[i]);
    div4.appendChild(mi4);
  }
}
```

As you can see, we repeat a certain amount of time the same function depending on how much inputs we have in the div `tempResult`:

```
var str = document.getElementById('tempStringX').value;
  var arrayOfStringsX = str.split('*');
  for(var i = 0; i < arrayOfStringsX.length; i++)
  {
    var divX = document.getElementById('divX');
    var miX = document.createElement('input');
    miX.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    miX.setAttribute('size', '5');
    miX.setAttribute('id', 'stringX' + (i+1));
    miX.setAttribute('value', arrayOfStringsX[i]);
    divX.appendChild(miX);
  }
```

The `X`, replaced by numbers each time, are important, the function will not properly work without it (except for the `divX`, I could generate the inputs inside the same div, but whatever). The above code is working perfectly.

What I'm trying to do, is to use a `for()` instead of `if...else()`, so that I don't need to manually edit the code each time we add a new div. I'm not very familiar with `for()` and my tries with the already existing ones in my code as models were not successful.

Here's how the HTML looks like:

```
<div id="tempResult">
    <input type="text" id="tempString1" value="valueTempString1" />
    <input type="text" id="tempString2" value="valueTempString2" />
    <input type="text" id="tempString3" value="valueTempString3" />
    <input type="text" id="tempString4" value="valueTempString4" />
</div>
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
<div id="div4"></div>
```

And if you wonder what this whole code is doing, [explanation's here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26081187/javascript-cut-string-and-return-in-different-inputs). Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The if loops in the code you posted would be used as a for loop. i.e, you would be iterating the same times the input count would be. So you can condense the same code into this.

```
var inputCount = document.getElementById('tempResult')
                         .getElementsByTagName('input').length;

// First loop that iterates over the input count
for (var j = 1; j <= inputCount; j++) {
    var str = document.getElementById('tempString' + j).value,
        arrayOfStrings = str.split('*');
    // Second loop would iterate over the strings that would be split
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfStrings.length; i++) {
        var div = document.getElementById('div' + j);
        var mi = document.createElement('input');
        mi.setAttribute('type', 'text');
        mi.setAttribute('size', '5');
        mi.setAttribute('id', 'string' + j + '-' + (i + 1));
        mi.setAttribute('value', arrayOfStrings[i]);
        div.appendChild(mi);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want the variable to have the number of the item? You could run all code inside the for statement and the variable name doesn't have to change.

```
thisdiv = document.getElementById('div'+i);
thisdiv....all changes to thisdiv go here
```

Comment: Thanks. Can it interfer with the `i` I already use inside the function? For example in the line 7 `for(var i = 0; i < arrayOfStrings1.length; i++)`. Because this loop generates more than the amount of `inputs` in the div `tempResult`, so the `i` will not have the same value. Sorry if the question semes stupid, as I said I'm not familiar with loops.

Comment: Yes please, because I'm struggling to understand how to get the final result. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Seems he beat me up. Glad you got an answer!